# x64 generate fcmov/fcomi for min

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, floating-point

I have a portion of code that is in a tight loop and it's do-ing a min of elements and it has to be done float by float. I tried using SSE but since it's a tight loop, the load/store actually made SSE version slower than the regular branching version. I am trying to use fcmov, but I can't get VS2010 to generate that. This is x64 so inline asm can't be used. Any thoughts on how to coax vs2010 to use fcmov/fcomi?

Thanks

Comment: Use an external assembler

Comment: I don't think you'll ever be able convince the 64-bit compiler to use `FCMOV` as that instruction uses the x87 registers, not the SSE registers.

Comment: You can compare the ieee754 floats x86 uses by treating them as signed integers, as long as no NANs are involved. You'd have to get around strict aliasing though...

Comment: but I guess that doesn't apply to x64 floating unit. So is there no way in x64 to not have a jump in a simple min check (there is SSE but like I said, that turned up slower than the jump version).

Comment: By comparing the floats as integers, you can use integer conditional move (CMOVcc) instructions. Unlike the horrible x87 legacy crap, those will be readily produced by compilers.

Comment: Do you have an article or suggestion on how this can be done, I don't think you can just compare a float as a signed int without some special ops right, since the representation is different.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles to a conditional move on gcc, don't know if VS does the same.

```
template<class T>
constexpr inline T min(const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
   return (lhs<rhs)?lhs:rhs;
}
```

Using intrinsics:
For processors that have **SSE4_1** Nahelem or newer?
Use aligned loads, so you might have to add a some loop fixing at start and/or end.

```
__m128 O1, O2, O3, mask;
...
mask = _mm_cmplt_ps(O2, O3); // O2 < O3
O1 = _mm_blendv_ps(O2, O3 ,mask); // O1 = (O2<O3)?O2:O3
```

Comment: yea i use pretty much exactly the same using a ternary operator, but in VS2010, it compiles to instructions with jb/jl (jumps) in them.

Comment: In GCC the compiler finds out *some* conversions to SIMD of its own if the optimization level is set high enough, maybe VC is that smart too?

Comment: I am using O2 already, the compiler just keeps using jumps :(

Comment: Added a method for using intrinsics, ie. using the SSE directly, this is for SSE4.1.